# Null Comparison in MySQL

Tags: mysql, null, comparison

I was trying to compare values of some fields while using **case when** in mysql. I found strange behavior. So I tried following query. It's returning me false in mysql. I can't get reason behind it. Any Help? 

`select if(null=null,'true','false');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the MySQL documentation at the [Working with null values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html) page:

> The NULL value can be surprising until you get used to it.
>   Conceptually, NULL means “a missing unknown value” and it is treated
>   somewhat differently from other values.

since NULL is "unknown", the comparison NULL = NULL will be unknown as well and will return NULL, and since NULL is not TRUE your function will return 'false'.

You could use IS NULL operator:

```
SELECT IF(NULL IS NULL, 'true', 'false')
```

or you can also use then [NULL-safe equal to operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to):

```
SELECT IF(NULL <=> NULL, 'true', 'false')
```

Answer (score 2):

you should do with `IS`

```
 SELECT IF(NULL IS NULL,'true','false');
```

or if you are comparing other field name then for example

```
 SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `field_name` IS NULL
```

or to negate it

```
 SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `field_name` IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

You can compare NULL in below way also:

```
SELECT IF (NULL<=>NULL,'True','False');
```

Answer (score 0):

**NULL isn't a value**; it's the lack of a value. So, logically, it cannot compare equally with itself.

This is not unique to MySQL; it is a phenomenon found across the field of computer programming (though there are some notable exceptions such as C).

The operator `IS` performs a more intelligent, null-aware "comparison", whereby `NULL IS NULL` evaluates to `TRUE`.